# Will this page cause memory leak？

Tags: php

I have a page of below , it loads a image for user and the url looks like 
someurl/page.php?path=a.jpg
when people visit this page  I find the memory usage increases fast
I m not sure if this page causes memory leak

```
 <?php
    $tar_path=urldecode($_GET['path']); 
    $strs=preg_split("/\./",$tar_path); 
    $small_name = $strs[0].'_small.'.$strs[1]; 
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
    if(file_exists($small_name))
    {
        $PSize = filesize($small_name );
        $picturedata = fread(fopen($small_name, "r"), $PSize);
        echo $picturedata;
    }else
    {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($tar_path);  
        $maxwidth = 150;  
        $maxheight = 0; 

        $pic_width = imagesx($im);  
        $pic_height = imagesy($im);  



        $widthratio = $maxwidth/$pic_width;  
        $resizewidth_tag = true;  



        $ratio = $widthratio;  

        $newwidth = $pic_width * $ratio;             
        $newheight = $pic_height * $ratio;         
        if(function_exists("imagecopyresampled"))  
        {  
            $newim = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);   
            imagecopyresampled($newim,$im,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$pic_width,$pic_height);   
        }  
        else  
        {  
            $newim = imagecreate($newwidth,$newheight);  
            imagecopyresized($newim,$im,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$pic_width,$pic_height);  
        }  

        imagejpeg($newim,$small_name);  
        imagedestroy($newim);  
        imagedestroy($im);
        $PSize = filesize($small_name );
        $picturedata = fread(fopen($small_name, "r"), $PSize);
        echo $picturedata;
    }         
    ?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: You need to debug. Maube [this](http://xdebug.org/archives/xdebug-general/1228.html) tool will help you. However, you can dig with `memory_get_usage` as well.

Answer (score 2):

The memory usage of the browser or the server?.

The php interpreter is supposed to release all memory upon ending the execution of the script. Memory consumption going up on the server in this case may indicate that working with images is heavy, but all memory should be released when done.

Comment: but I found memory of server never released

Comment: Interesting... Did it release after a while on its own?. These functions interact with the imagemagick (I think) suite, that may be doing things on its own... Or maybe there's a leak on your php code, but that should clear itself.